# How to make a reference in a formula dynamic on cell value base

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reference

I want to make this formula dynamic by using the values in column C to complete the reference to the right file. That way I can just drag the formula down instead of altering the dates all the time. Some help would be very much appreciated.

Already tried the indirect function but this only seems to work on open workbooks.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('G:\AGL''s & TC''s\Performance\2019\ASHIFT\Januari\
["&TEXT(C8,"ddmmyyyy")&".xlsm]PICKING'!$KD$5:$KD$200;MATCH($B$3;'G:\AGL''s & 
TC''s\Performance\2019\ASHIFT\Januari\ 
["&TEXT(C8,"ddmmyyyy")&".xlsm]PICKING'!$A$5:$A$200;0));0)
```

Mapping is correct. When i use the actual filename the expected results are shown.

Comment: Where is `INDIRECT()` formula? Indirect function should work.

Comment: Does it actually need to remain dynamic, or is this just to make it easier to enter the relevant formulas initially?

Comment: @Harun24HR - Don't want to make use of indirect() function knowing this only works on open workbooks.

Comment: @ Rory - Doesn't need to stay dynamic. It just makes it easier to apply this on a whole year's data

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot use a formula to generate a filename for `INDEX()`, `INDIRECT()` etc. functions. Excel just doesn't support this.

Excel keeps register of references to external workbooks, and it needs static data for it, so formulas are no-go here.